# Android insert multiple sms in "content://sms/" with contentresolver.bulkInsert() : too slow

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to insert multiple sms in "content://sms/" table. let's say 500 sms.

my code is :

```
ContentValues [500] valuesarray = new ContentValues[];

for(int i=0;i<values.size();i++){
     valuesarray[i] = values.get(i);
}

getContentResolver().bulkInsert(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), valuesarray);
```

It works, but it is extremely slow, and it makes no difference with insert() method. I serched on the net, and found methods like :

```
try {
    database.beginTransaction();

    for (ContentValues initialValues : allValues) {
        values = initialValues == null ? new ContentValues() : new ContentValues(initialValues);
        rowId = insertEvent(database, values);
        if (rowId > 0)
            rowsAdded++;
    }

    database.setTransactionSuccessful();
} catch (SQLException ex) {

} finally {
    database.endTransaction();
}
```

But this is for personnal databases. How can I use a method like this with Android's "content://sms/" provider?

Comment: As far as I can see the MmsSmsProvider class (which if my memory doesn't fail me is the content provider you are using) does not properly implement bulkInsert or applyBatch - i.e. it's not using an SQLite transaction to speed up multiple database operations (this was at least the case in ICS if i remember correctly).

Comment: Yes resolver.bulkInsert() is the same as doind resolver.insert() in a loop. This method is a joke. Transaction thing makes all the difference, you pass from minutes to few seconds, but I can't find a way to do it for content://sms provider.

Comment: Not really, you're pretty much _f*cked_ if the provider is poorly implemented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I use a method like this with Android's "content://sms/" provider?

You can't, sorry.

(besides, that provider is not part of the Android SDK and may not exist on all devices, anyway, so you should not be using it)